# Magento 2 UI component. Disable field based on values of two other fields

Tags: magento2, uicomponent

I need the product field "disabled" attribute to be dependent from two other checkbox fields. For now I have it dependent from one field like this (DataModfier):

```
protected function customizeFieldSub(array $meta)
{
    $dependentPath = $this->arrayManager->findPath('show_email_for_instant_price', $meta, null, 'children');

    if ($dependentPath) {
        $meta = $this->arrayManager->merge(
            $dependentPath . static::META_CONFIG_PATH,
            $meta,
            [
                'dataScope' => 'dependent_field',
                'validation' => [
                    'required-entry' => true,
                    'validate-zero-or-greater' => true
                ],
                'formElement' => 'input',
                'additionalClasses' => 'admin__field-small',
                'imports' => [
                    'disabled' => 
                        '!ns = ${ $.ns }, index = field1:checked'
                ]
            ]
        );
    }
    return $meta;
}
```

I need something like this:

```
               'imports' => [
                    'disabled' =>
                        '(!ns = ${ $.ns }, index = field1:checked) && (!ns = ${ $.ns }, index = field2:checked)'
                ]
```

But it doesn't work this way. And also it doesn't allow to use functions there. How can I achieve what I want? I need the field to be disabled until you enable two checkboxes

Answer (score 1):

Following are 2 different solutions for handling field dependency:

https://www.hungersoft.com/info/dependent-fields-ui-component-form-magento2-boolean-fields

https://www.hungersoft.com/info/dependent-fields-ui-component-form-magento2-without-js

I have tried both the solutions and they work for simple cases such as field dependency on Yes/No values, a list a values, etc. The solutions discussed are using XML, but you should be able to convert the logic to array.